# ArcPy SelectLayerByLocation cannot retrieve selected features

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I have two line feature layers, they intersect at mid point of each line segment at 90 degree angle. Let's say, they are Layer1 and Layer2, I want to iterate through Layer1 and use the SelectLayerByLocation tool to find the line segment from Layer2 that intersect it, then get its 'Name' field value and apply it to the Layer1's line segment's 'Name' field. I've searched a lot, couldn't find working ArcPy script for this to work, I have the following script to start with:

```
# open the Layer1 and Layer2
Layer1 = base_dir + 'conveyance.shp'
Layer2 = base_dir + 'sa2dcenterline.shp'

Lyr1 = ap.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Layer1, "barrel")
Lyr2 = ap.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Layer2, "sa2d")

# iterate through each line feature in Lyr2 to intersect with Lyr1
with ap.da.SearchCursor(Lyr2, ['SHAPE@', 'Name']) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        cur_intersect = ap.SelectLayerByLocation_management(Lyr1, "INTERSECT", row[0], '', 'NEW_SELECTION')
        # cnt = int(ap.GetCount_management(cur_intersect).getOutput(0))
        # if cnt > 0:
        #   print(f'{row[1]} intersects with {cnt} features.')
        lyr_sel = ap.MakeFeatureLayer_management(cur_intersect, "sel")

        # here is where I am trying to get the selected Lyr1's Name field
        # and assign it to Lyr2's feature's Name field, the following 
        # surely will fail as it is trying to assign to a tuple,
        # i included it here just as placeholder
        with ap.da.SearchCursor(lyr_sel, ['Name']) as cur1:
            for row_sel in cur1:
                row[2] = 'b-' + str(int(row_sel[0]))
                break
        lyr_sel = None
    pass
```

As you can see from above, I can iterate through the records in Layer2 and select by intersection from Layer1, but then I couldn't find way to get the selected Layer1's feature and get to its attributes, then update the corresponding 'Name' field in Layer2.

Comment: Have you looked at [Spatial Join (Analysis) - ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm) or [Add Spatial Join (Data Management) - ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/add-spatial-join.htm) ?

Comment: It looks like you're not tracking selection sets correctly. A layer is a combination of a source with selection and other properties. You don't need to make a new one so much as CLEAR or NEW the selection each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program is mostly correct. It needs two updates to make it work:

First, change `with ap.da.SearchCursor(Lyr2, ['SHAPE@', 'Name']) as cur:` to `with ap.da.UpdateCursor(Lyr2, ['SHAPE@', 'Name']) as cur:`

Second, change the bottom section of the code to:

```
with ap.da.SearchCursor(lyr_sel, ['Name']) as cur1:
    for row_sel in cur1:
        row[2] = 'b-' + str(int(row_sel[0]))
        break
cur.updateRow(row)
ap.Delete_management(lyr_sel)
```

So, basically, need to make the update layer to be editable, and delete the temporary selection layer after each use.